# au build complains about file not found or accessible

Tags: aurelia

I've added apollo-client via `au install apollo-client` and now when I run `au build` I get a bunch 'file not found' messages:

```
Tracing apollo-client...
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/whatwg-fetch.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/graphql/language/printer.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/redux.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/graphql-anywhere.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/symbol-observable.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/apollo-link-core.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/whatwg-fetch.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/graphql/language/printer.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/redux.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/graphql-anywhere.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/symbol-observable.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: /some/path/Client/src/apollo-link-core.js
| Requested by: /some/path/Client/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
Tracing whatwg-fetch...
Tracing graphql/language/printer...
Tracing redux...
Tracing graphql-anywhere...
Tracing symbol-observable...
Tracing apollo-link-core...
Tracing core-js...
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, this is one of the things that is currently still a real pain in the butt with our CLI. If you install a dependency that itself has dependencies, you have to make sure you update the `aurelia.json` file to include all of those dependencies in your `vendor-bundle` as well. The CLI team is aware of this issue and is working to fix this pain point.

They're aware of it because I complain incessantly about this. I'm pretty good at complaining.

***UPDATE 2018-01-18***

The CLI now has `au install` that will install a dependency and then try to properly set it up in your `aurelia.json` file.

You can avoid these issues completely by switching over to using Webpack as your module loader/bundler when creating a new project with our CLI. You will have to choose to create a "Custom" build, but I've recently moved over, and I have to say the Webpack experience when using the Aurelia CLI is quite nice.